# Obtaining value from named form input

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this HTML

```
<input type="text" name="message"/>
```

With this PHP

```
$message = 'Blank message';

if ( isset( $post['message'] ) ) 
    $message = sanitize_text_field( $post['message'] );
```

`$Message` is always "Blank message"

I cannot see how this is wrong. After attempting to get the input value, I have no other code so I know the rest of it is working, but I am unable to obtain the value.

Comment: What is `$post`?

Comment: @u_mulder https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post Am I better off using _POST?

Comment: "Contains data from the current post", you know what is post here?

Comment: On further reading of the loop; I am adding my field on top of a plugin. More context here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622714/posting-custom-mycred-transfer-form-value-to-wp-database I asked this new question as I thought I had narrowed down the issue

Comment: I think you really misunderstand what is `$post` and what is `$_POST`.

Comment: Could you do a var_dump($post) and see what is contained in it? or return a '<pre>',print_r($post,1),'</pre>'

Answer (score 0):

sup, you gotta change the way you're calling the array, it is `$_POST`, and not `$post`

Comment: `if ( isset( $_POST['message'] ) )   $message = sanitize_text_field($_POST['message'] );` also returns "Blank message"

Comment: Are you sure that you're submiting the form correctly? Check if it is `method="POST"` and if `action="your_correct_page.php"`

Comment: more context here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622714/posting-custom-mycred-transfer-form-value-to-wp-database but thought I would ask differently as no responses

Comment: By looking at it, you're right with using `$post`, since is the parameter of your function. It looks like you're writing the input by using the function `mycred_pro_transfer_message_field() `. If you're not inside of an existing form and you're just passing this to the HTML, it won't work cause you need a form to send data.

Comment: The final HTML prints as https://pastebin.pl/view/e5e64abc where I am using `custom_transfer-message` rather than my example name attribute above.

Comment: The HTML is missing the `action`, but i assume you took it off for the question. The problem might be in how you're ´passing this value to the function. If you're calling the function like `your_function($_POST['custom_transfer-message'])`, it will send the string to the function, and not the array. Maybe that's the problem, cause you're gonna be trying to access a key on a variable that isn't an array, and it will allways return `false`

Comment: I half understand, but my db says `a:4:{s:8:"ref_type";s:4:"user";s:3:"tid";s:16:"TXID1604153101";
s:7:"message";s:3:"personal message";s:23:"custom_transfer-message";s:13:"Blank message";}` so the "Blank message" value is getting through - so it's got to be that the ` $message =  $post['custom_transfer-message']` is not reading the value.

Comment: Something is wrong on your function. How are you calling this function? It looks a little confusing, cause you're passing a parameter `$post`, and then adding it to `$data[]`. Again, the way the function currently is, it is expecting the `$post` to be an `array`, wich is not at all needed, since you just wanna compare a string, and not the intire array. MAKE SURE you're passing `$_POST` and not `$_POST['custom_transfer-message']`, otherwise, the if it will always be `false`

Answer (score 0):

Look to the method of your form. Are you using the `GET` method than you use `$_GET['variable']` is it the `POST` method than you use `$_POST['variable']`.